# R - Apply a command to all rows and cols in a matrix. logically change the values used in the command

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I have two matrices.
(1) "mat" is n*n (3*3) and contains the proximity of the items to each other

```
mat = matrix(c(1,0,0.4,0,1,0.6,0.4,0.6,1),nrow=3,ncol=3)
colnames(mat) = c("A","B","C")
rownames(mat) = colnames(mat)
```

(2) "ev" is x*n (4*3) and contains, how often the items of "mat" occur in each of the other dimension (rows) in "ev"

```
ev = matrix(c(2,0,3,0,1,4,3,1,2,0,0,4),nrow=4,ncol=3)
colnames(ev)=colnames(mat)
rownames(ev)=c("LA","LE","LO","LU")
```

Now I want a new matrix "new" with the same dimensions as "ev" where the value of a cell is:
the sum of the products of every column of the current row in "ev" with the respective columns of the row in "mat" that is the same as the current column in "ev". This needs to be applied rowwise and columnwise in the new matrix.

---

in a line by line command it would look like this:

How to compute the columns (if 1 to n) of the first row of the new matrix

```
new[1,1]=sum(ev[1,1:3]*mat[1,1:3])
new[1,2]=sum(ev[1,1:3]*mat[2,1:3])
new[1,n]=sum(ev[1,1:3]*mat[n,1:3])
```

How to compute the columns of the last row (if 1 to n rows)

```
new[n,1]=sum(ev[n,1:3]*mat[1,1:3])
new[n,2]=sum(ev[n,1:3]*mat[2,1:3])
new[n,n]=sum(ev[n,1:3]*mat[n,1:3])
```

As you can see, the only thing I really need to do, is to define that when I want to compute the whole matrix, the row chosen in "ev" changes with the row of "new" and the row chosen in "mat" changes with the column of "new".

Afterwards the new matrix (in this example) should look like this:

```
new=matrix(2.8,0,3,1.6,2.2,4,3,3.4,3.4,2.4,3,4.6,nrow=4,ncol=3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing matrix multiplication. R uses `%*%` for matrix multiplication:

```
ev %*% mat
#      A   B   C
# LA 2.8 2.2 3.4
# LE 0.0 4.0 2.4
# LO 3.0 3.0 3.0
# LU 1.6 3.4 4.6

all(ev %*% mat == new)
# [1] TRUE
```

See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) for more details.

If you would prefer to make your own function, I would recommend reading about `for` loops. If you search "for loops in r" [you can find many beginner tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=for+loops+in+r).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't expect it to be that simple! I tried to get started with loops, but I couldn't really figure out how to work this out.